# copy from one object, change keys but keep the same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Hi I want to copy a JavaScript object that lives in an external json file. It looks like this:

and via the code I want to change the keys on each array without changing the values of it. The values for the last key needs be an array instead of just vales

```
{ "items": [
  { "namezz": "Bike", "price": 100 },
  { "namezz": "TV", "price": 700 },
  { "namezz": "Album", "price": 10 },
  { "namezz": "Book", "price": 5 },
  { "namezz": "Phone", "price": 500 },
  { "namezz": "Computer", "price": 1000 },
  { "namezz": "Keyboard", "price": 25 }
]
}
```

It needs to looks like this:

```
[
  { "name": "Bike", "data": [100] },
  { "name": "TV", "data": [700] },
  { "name": "Album", "data": [10] },
  { "name": "Book", "data": [5] },
  { "name": "Phone", "data": [500] },
  { "name": "Computer", "data": [1000] },
  { "name": "Keyboard", "data": [25] }
]
```

code that I've tried:

```
 const itemNames =  simple.map((xxx) => {

        return ("name" + xxx.namezz + "data: [" + xxx.price + "]")
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is returning string whereas you need a object, i.e

```
return { name:xxx.namezz , data: [xxx.price] }
```

---

Alternatively you can use `map` and  `destructuring`

```js
let obj = { "items": [{ "namezz": "Bike", "price": 100 },{ "namezz": "TV", "price": 700 },{ "namezz": "Album", "price": 10 },{ "namezz": "Book", "price": 5 },{ "namezz": "Phone", "price": 500 },{ "namezz": "Computer", "price": 1000 },{ "namezz": "Keyboard", "price": 25 }]}

let final = obj.items.map(({ price, namezz }) => ({ namezz, data: [price] }))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track with the `map()` method. The way you've used `map()` will result in an array of strings. Here's an example of using `map()` to get the output you requested (new array of objects).

```js
const myObject = {
  "items": [{
      "namezz": "Bike",
      "price": 100
    },
    {
      "namezz": "TV",
      "price": 700
    },
    {
      "namezz": "Album",
      "price": 10
    },
    {
      "namezz": "Book",
      "price": 5
    },
    {
      "namezz": "Phone",
      "price": 500
    },
    {
      "namezz": "Computer",
      "price": 1000
    },
    {
      "namezz": "Keyboard",
      "price": 25
    }
  ]
};

const result = myObject.items.map(x => ({ name: x.namezz, data: [x.price] }));

console.log(result);
```